# Intersection of trinary matrices

Tags: algorithm, binary, intersection

Consider 3 matrices of binary variables b0,b1,b2,b3. All these matrices have same number of column but can be different number of rows. Each element of the matrix can have three values 1,0 or 2 where 2 represent don't care. I have to find binary strings that presents in all three matrices. For example consider the following 3 matrices:

```
matrix1:
1 0 2 2
2 2 0 0
1 2 1 1

matrix2:
2 2 0 2
1 0 1 2

matrix3:
2 2 1 2
1 2 2 1
2 2 2 1
```

So, for this example string b0=1,b1=0,b2=1,b3=1 is present in all matrices. Because, in matrix1, b0=1,b1=2,b2=1,b3=1 is same as 1011. In matrix2, b0=1,b1=0,b2=1,b3=2 is same as 1011 and in matrix3, b0=2,b1=2,b3=2,b3=1 is same as 1011.

How to find all binary strings that exists in all 3 matrices?

Comment: `2` is not a binary **value**. There are no variables shown. About the "how to": Write program code. Where is yours?

Comment: A question about an algorithm shouldn't be tied to a specific language/platform.

Comment: what exactly is your problem? do you need an efficient algorithm? how many matrices are there? how rows does each matrix have at most? is a "binary string" always of length 4? is the "binary string" always equal to a matrix row or can it span multiple rows?

Comment: yes, I need an efficient algorithm. Number of matrices can be upto 100. Each matrix can have maximum 1000 rows. A "binary string" always of length 4. A "binary string" always have to be equal to a matrix row. It can not span multiple rows.

Comment: `b0` ... `b3` are **four**, not **three** names. And they seem to hold **three** different values, not **two**. Maybe you shoudl first get the problem right. And look up what "binary" means.

Comment: Each row of 3 matrices have 4 variables b0,b1,b2 ,b3 which I call a "binary string". matrix1[0][0] is b0=1,matrix1[0][1] is b1=0,matrix1[0][2] is b2=2 and matrix[0][3] is b3=2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to "expand" each row to its set of possibilities, so for example 1022 gets expanded to:

> 1000
>    1001
>    1010
>    1011

Then, it's convenient to convert each string to an integer (a single byte integer since the "strings" are 4 bit long) and place in a sorted array, or even a set.

Next step is to sort groups by length, from the smallest to the largest, then iterate the smallest group values and see that it exists in all other groups, this is very fast because of the preparation work in the "parsing" step.

Every value that passes for all groups is a match.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that simplest and reasonably efficient algorithm will be to brute-force check all possible combinations. Start with 0000 then 0001, then 0010 etc. With each of them, iterate each matrix and compare values. On first match, go to next matrix, on non-match, immediately reject.

You will have to iterate each matrix maximum 16 times, which is still O(N) from size of matrix.

If you want to optimize actual comparison, you can precompute lookup strings for each matrix. Create reverse bitmasks for 0-allowed and 1-allowed and AND them with bitmasks of has-0 and has-1 of query string. If any of two results is non-zero (you can just add or OR them and check result), string won't be matching.

In any case, it should be very fast with any kind of comparison implementation, as you will be doing only 16*(1000+1000+1000) rather than (1000*1000*1000) operations you probably were considering.